# Compare items of two tuples in different List python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Hello freinds i need your help.
I want to compare between two lists of tuples ,if  there is more than one identical value between the two tuples I print this result
exp :

```
L1 = [('G', 'T'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'U'), ('U', 'I'), ('I', 'P')]
L2 = [('E', 'G'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'P')]
```

> > output:
> >       [0,1]

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I don't get your expected output. Probably if you share your code, we might understand better.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I try but I can not handle the elements of the list like tuple , i want to compare every each tuple of the seconde list with each tuple of list 1 and if there is more than identical value between the 2 tuple i print the index of  tuple 1 from list 1 and tuple 2 from list2

Comment: Dont repeat what you said in your question. Add a more detailed example (with some code).

Comment: the output is the index of identical tuple in each list [0,1]

Comment: (G,T) is in range 0 in list 1 and in range 1 in the second list

Comment: Can lists contain duplicates?

Comment: duplicate tuple ? yeah sure

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
L1 = [('G', 'T'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'U'), ('U', 'I'), ('I', 'P')]
L2 = [('E', 'G'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'P')]

indices = [[L1.index(s),i] for i, s in enumerate(L2) if s in L1]

# print the first match (in this case there is only one match)
print(indices[0])
[0, 1]
```

---

Explanation of `[[L1.index(s),i] for i, s in enumerate(L2) if s in L1]`:

- `for i, s in enumerate(L2)`: i is the index, s in the tuple element of L2
- `if s in L1`: this checks if the current `s` is also in L1
- `[L1.index(s),i]`: this returns a list of the index

P.S: For duplicates this may not behave well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little more dynamic of a solution. I altered your input a little to get a different test case. This will work for duplicates and also works in O(N) time.

```
from collections import defaultdict
L1 = [('G', 'T'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'U'), ('U', 'I'), ('I', 'P'), ('U', 'I')]
L2 = [('E', 'G'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'P'), ('U', 'I')]
S1 = defaultdict(list)
S2 = defaultdict(list)
for indx, element in enumerate(L1):
    S1[element].append(indx)
for indx, element in enumerate(L2):
    S2[element].append(indx)

duplicate_elements = set(S1).intersection(set(S2))
print("Mutual elements:", *[(S1[dup], S2[dup]) for dup in duplicate_elements])
```

Output:

```
Mutual elements: ([0], [1]) ([3, 5], [3])
```

Comment: this is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @makis Take a close look though. "duplicate tuple ? yeah sure". Your solution will fail for duplicates. Similarly your solution is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: it's true but this comment was just posted + in the question there is no information about it.

Comment: @makis that comment is older than your answer... Thats why I did the above solution (which answers the OPs other use-cases).